# Need some logic in powershell to measure latest

Tags: powershell

I have a text file like this:

```
9/22/2015
8/16/2015
8/15/2015
7/30/2015
7/1/2015
6/30/2015
```

I am trying to measure-latest of the entries which has month not equal to 9 or 8.

I am out of logic and what I tried is given below:

```
$split1 = Get-Content "C:\RDS\split1.txt"
foreach($spl1 in $split1)
{
 $sp1 = $spl1 -split '/'
 $spl1M = $sp1[0]
 if(($spl1M -ne $past_month) -and ($spl1M -ne $cur_month))
 {
  $array3 += $spl1 
 }else
 {
$array3 | Measure-Latest | Add-Content "C:\month.txt"
 }
}
```

In short: when I am having 2 elements with month 7 I need to get latest among those two and write it to a file. Same goes to all others whose months are not 8 and 9 (if loop will protect that). [Measure-Latest](https://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2008/07/16/measure-latest-finding-the-latest-date-time/) is a function.

Can someone please provide me a logic to achieve this?

**Edit:**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can group your dates by month, sort them, and then choose the largest date for each month:

```
$dateGroup = gc "C:\RDS\split1.txt" | Group-Object -Property { $dt=[datetime]$_; $dt.Month } | ?{ $_.Name -ne "8" -and $_.Name -ne "9" }

$dateGroup | %{ [pscustomobject]@{"Count"=$_.Count; "Name"=$_.Name; "Group"=$($_.Group | Sort-Object -Descending | Select-Object -first 1) } }
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am getting an array of each month. I need to be able to omit the elements of months 8 and 9 and then get latest of each other months. Can you help me on this.?

Comment: Yeah, you just need to filter those out. I added the where-object ("?") to exclude those.

Comment: Working, but again I have the output like this:

Count Name                      Group                                                                                                                                    
----- ----                      -----                                                                                                                                    
    2 7                         {7/30/2015, 7/1/2015}

How to get 7/30/2015 from that.?

Comment: The count for how many dates are in a given month are output from the Group-Object call. I'll put in an edit to show you.

Comment: Much appreciated, but I have edited my question just to show you what I am getting when I execute your piece of code. The final output what I want is the most recent one of every array, which means latest of month 7, 6, 5 etc etc.

Comment: @serverstackqns Ok, I've updated again, try it now. It should just spit out the max date and not the list.