# Retrieve latest value of each month

Tags: powershell

This is a continuation from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481129/need-some-logic-in-powershell-to-measure-latest). Sorry to ask as a repetition, but I am not able to move forward without this and I am tired by Googling. I am not able to give bounty to this question till tomorrow.

I want to retrieve latest value of each array of each month, may be 7, 6, 5 etc etc. Any solutions or thoughts please?

Expected output:

```
$array3 = 7/30/2015
          6/30/2015
          5/31/2015
```

All latest dates in an array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need some logic in powershell to measure latest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481129/need-some-logic-in-powershell-to-measure-latest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how your output should looks like (would always be much easier if you provide an example) but if you want to retrieve **a list of dates containing only the last of each month**, try this:

```
gc $filePath |
 sort { [datetime]$_ } -Descending |
  group {([datetime]$_).Month } |
   % {$_.Group | select -first 1}
```

It sorts the dates descending, groups it by month and then selects the first one of each other.

The **output** is:

```
9/22/2015
8/16/2015
7/30/2015
6/30/2015
```

If you need the reverse order, just append `| sort { [datetime]$_ }`to the script. If performance matters, you should remove the `-Descending` parameter from the first `sort` and use `select -last 1` instead of `sekect -first 1`

**Edit:** 
Added filter for month not 8 or 9 and sorted the date:

```
$array3 = gc $filePath |
 ? { $tmp = [datetime]$_; $tmp.Month -ne "8" -and $tmp.Month -ne "9" } |
 sort { [datetime]$_ } -Descending|
  group {([datetime]$_).Month } |
   % {$_.Group | select -first 1}
   sort { [datetime]$_ } -Descending
```

Output of `$array3` is now:

```
7/30/2015
6/30/2015
```

Note: The date `5/31/2015` wasnt in your previous list.

Comment: Yes, I read it. I would just like to see an example of your desired output.

Comment: Thank you, but that that was an easy frag ;-)

Comment: Instead of the repeated casts why not just have a `%{[datetime]$_}` after GC. It would remove a bunch of clutter.

Comment: of course, thats also possible but would require to parse the datetime back to the desired output at the end of the script.